# Make script run every time page is reloaded

Tags: javascript

I am wanting this script to run every time the page is reloaded, the problem is I only know how to run it in the console window of chrome. Do i need to learn how to make an extension or is there another way to do this?

```js
var data = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var newOpponent = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
newOpponent[32].id = "newOpponent";
document.getElementById("newOpponent");
document.getElementById("newOpponent").click();
//if(data[67].value > 20){
//    data.innerHTML = "<td style="width:40%; text-align:left; border:2px solid red;">23</td>";
//}

console.log("Strength: " + data[67].innerHTML);
console.log("Attack: " + data[70].innerHTML);
console.log("Defense: " + data[73].innerHTML);
console.log("Agility: " + data[76].innerHTML);
console.log("Stamina: " + data[79].innerHTML);

var strength = parseInt(data[67].innerHTML);
var attack = parseInt(data[70].innerHTML);
var defense = parseInt(data[73].innerHTML);
var agility = parseInt(data[76].innerHTML);
var stamina = parseInt(data[79].innerHTML);

if (attack > 20 || strength > 20 || defense > 20 || agility > 20 || stamina > 20){
    alert("One of the stats is too high, finding new opponent.");
}

if (Number.isInteger(attack) == true && attack > 20 ) {
    data[67].style.border = "thick solid red";
    document.getElementById("newOpponent").click();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want it to run *every time page is reloaded* or *to run constantly*?

Comment: I will fix the wording, Every time the page is reloaded :)

Comment: Are you trying to run this script whenever a page is reloaded in chome? If so you should try looking for an extension that runs a custom script for each page.

Answer (score 1):

Is it [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) what you're looking for?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // do your stuff
};
```

Comment: This will not work because when the page is reloaded, the chrome console clears.

Comment: @OleTuck oh so you need to keep the log, right? Note that chrome dev tools console includes a checkbox to preserve logs. Maybe it is ok for your use case. Otherwise I think you'll need an extension or something like that. It does not seem to be possible to solve it from a page code.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Here your code!
});
```

[jQuery learning site](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

[jQuery API site](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your demande, you would run your custom script on the page. If true, you could use the extension Tampermonkey Chrome for your objectif about injecting the custom script on a page

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=fr